# Dataframe with a single Column Value

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

I'm using pyodbc to get the data out of a pervasive database.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

conn_str = "Driver={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface};ServerName=SC220;DBQ=RDP51"
db = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
c = db.cursor()
sql = "select * from hreserve"

c.execute(sql)
df = pd.DataFrame(c.fetchall())
```

with this I get a output like this.

```
                                                   0
0  [G0, N,  , M, 6,     78, LEADER  , 0, 6, 2015-...
1  [G0, N,  , P, 6,     79, 417     , 0, 6, 2015-...
2  [G0,  ,  , P, 6,     82, 420     , 0, 6, 2015-...
3  [G0,  ,  , P, 8,     77, 102     , 0, 2, 2015-...
4  [G0, N,  , P, 6,     80, 202     , 0, 6, 2015-...
```

How would I separate this data into different columns that I could then attach a column value to?

Edited to show how I was placing the data into the dataframe.

Comment: is the source data a list of comma separated values? can you post a full of data if possible or reproduce it for us in code?

Comment: How are you inserting that result into a data frame?

Comment: are you using `pd.read_sql`? If yes, please write the full code. From the current code I don't see how you are getting this output.

Comment: Forgot to add the part of the code where I got the result into the dataframe. I've added that.

Answer (score 1):

A bit tricky without having the full dataset and reproducible example. However, if the information is coming as one columns, all you need is transform that into a `series` and attach to a new `DataFrame`:

```py
### assuming this is your dataset:
df = pd.DataFrame({0:[
['G0', 'N',  '', 'M', 6,     78, 'LEADER'  , 0, 6],
['G0', 'N',  '', 'P', 6,     79, 417     , 0, 6], 
['G0',  '',  '', 'P', 6,     82, 420     , 0, 6],
['G0',  '', '' , 'P', 8,     77, 102     , 0, 2], 
['G0', 'N', '', 'P', 6,     80, 202     , 0, 6]]}
)

Out[1]: 
                                  0
0  [G0, N, , M, 6, 78, LEADER, 0, 6]
1     [G0, N, , P, 6, 79, 417, 0, 6]
2      [G0, , , P, 6, 82, 420, 0, 6]
3      [G0, , , P, 8, 77, 102, 0, 2]
4     [G0, N, , P, 6, 80, 202, 0, 6]


### assing your data is saved to 'df':
df = df[0].apply(pd.Series)

Out[2]: 
    0  1 2  3  4   5       6  7  8
0  G0  N    M  6  78  LEADER  0  6
1  G0  N    P  6  79     417  0  6
2  G0       P  6  82     420  0  6
3  G0       P  8  77     102  0  2
4  G0  N    P  6  80     202  0  6
```

Comment: Applying pd.Series to a column separates elements as lists into new columns?

Comment: If they are nested like the example above yes

Comment: your a dang genius, +1!  Now, doing all that and applying column names too. That would be wizardry.

Comment: just do df.columns = ['list','of','names'] afterwards

Answer (score 0):

assuming `df` is your current dataframe... you can do:

```
pd.DataFrame(df[0].tolist(), columns = ['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6','c7','c8','c9'])
```

you can replace the column names with whatever you want to name them